# Visiting every value in a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to build a function to visit every value in a multi-dimensional array that has no limit to dimensions.

The depth of each value is generated.

```js
var array = [[0, [[1, [2, [3, []]]],[4, []],[5, [6, []]],[7, [8, [9, []]]],[10, []]]]];

function visitall(a) {
  for (i = 0; i < (a.length); i++) {
      console.log(a[i][0])
      for (j = 0; j < (a[i][1].length); j++) {
          console.log(a[i][1][j][0])
          for (n = 0; n < (a[i][1][j][1].length); n++) {
              console.log(a[i][1][j][1][n][0])
          }
      }
  }
}

visitall(array)
```

Comment: maybe use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion.

Use `Array.isArray` to check if variable is array. If it is, do a `forEach` and call the `visitall` function again.

```js
function visitall(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) a.forEach(visitall);
  else console.log(a); //Not an array, so console.log
}


var array = [[0, [[1, [2, [3, []]]],[4, []],[5, [6, []]],[7, [8, [9, []]]],[10, []]]]];

visitall(array);
```

---

Or you can `join`, `split` and `filter` so you can get all the number in the array. You can now loop as normal.

```js
var array = [[0, [[1, [2, [3, []]]],[4, []],[5, [6, []]],[7, [8, [9, []]]],[10, []]]]];

var result = array.join().split(',').filter(o => o !== '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `a.forEach(visitall);` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NinaScholz :)

Answer (score 2):

just use recursion

```js
var array = [
  [0, [[1, [2, [3, []]]], [4, []], [5, [6, []]], [7, [8, [9, []]]], [10, []]]]
];

function visit(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) visit(a[i]);
  } else {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

visit(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple to loop over any multidimensional array using reduce.

```
function flatten(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, next) => {
      return prev.concat(flatten(next));
    }, []);
  } else {
    return arr;
  }
}

console.log(flatten([1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]])); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

You can flatten it or do whatever you want directly in reduce function

Answer (score 1):

use recursion:

```
function logall(a){
  if( typeof(a)=='object' )
    for(var j=0;j<(a.length);j++)   
      logall(a[j]);
  else
   console.log(a)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a generic use you should write a recursive function as i can see the depth of your array is not fixed!
here is an example of how you can do it :

```js
var array = [[0,[
[1,[2,[3,[]]]],
[4,[]],
[5,[6,[]]],
[7,[8,[9,[]]]],
[10,[]]
]
]
]


function visit(a){
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    a.map((value) => {
     visit(value);
    })
  } else {
    console.log(a)
  }
}

visit(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES6

You can achieve using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to visit every value in a multi-dimensional array with the help of [`recursion function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion).

**DEMO**

```js
var arr=[[0, [[1, [2, [3, []]]],[4, []],[5, [6, []]],[7, [8, [9, []]]],[10, []]]]];

let visitall = (arr) =>{
    arr.forEach(v=>Array.isArray(v)?visitall(v):console.log(v))
}

visitall(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```